# "I have some advise for you"

Tags: word-choice

Is this sentence correct?

How about "I have some suggestions for you"

does either of these sound condescending? Are there any better alternatives to make suggestions/advise to someone?

Comment: *Advise* is a verb. You need *advice*, which is a noun. But - yes - "I have some advice for you" is condescending. "I wonder if I could make a couple of suggestions" is pleasant and informal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a spelling error "Advice" is the noun "Advise" is the verb. Apart from that the English is correct.

Is it "condescending" depends on the context. Are you in a position in which advice is expected? If you are not sure whether advice is welcome, you can always ask

> Would you like some advice?

or

> I've some advice for you, if you'd like to hear it.

There's always a dialogue and a social context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wonder if it is correct to shorten "I have some advice for you" into "I've some advice for you"

Comment: It would certainly be fine in speech